# constexpr function with no argument

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am getting confused around this snippet:

```
constexpr int f(bool b) {
  return b ? throw 0 : 0; }
constexpr int f() { return f(true); }
```

directly from the [c++ draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5).
The point I am stucked with is *why* the standard defines as ill-formed the case of a `constexpr` function without arguments (stated in the same link).
May anyone clarify?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is "*if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression*". It's not about the function `f()` taking no arguments; it's about the fact that there's no set of arguments you could give it that would make it return a usable value - it always calls `f(true)`, which throws an exception.

To re-iterate: a `constexpr` function without arguments can certainly be well-formed. But for the given example, it is not.

Also of note is "diagnostic not required". That means that a compiler is free to accept the construct anyway. Indeed, GCC compiles the example in your question without complaining.